# Ubuntu can't boot After updating BIOS! , But in recovery mode works , how can I fix this?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, bios, gpu-driver, recovery-mode

My Ubuntu can't log in after I updated my BIOS, It only boots into Ubuntu Recovery mode? Ubuntu forums say, Check your Additional driver's tab on *Software & updates* section, I check that, But it says NO Drivers available?"

Comment: Can you provide more information? What happens when you try to select `ubuntu` from the boot menu? what happens if you choose `resume` from the recovery menu?

Comment: when I do regular booting option from GRUB, it just show a blank screen for long time,  after I choose recovery booting option from GRUB, it loads configuration after, It prompts Option like a resume, makes free space, finds Broken packages ....     I choose Resume Option, It normally boots into the Recovery mode on Ubuntu,     This all happen after i updated my BIOS from my windows machine, by the way, I am using Dual Boot .

Comment: is their any problem to run a system in fully recovery mode,    there is any drawback?

Comment: I didn't understand what happens for you after you select "resume" from the recovery menu, but if it works for you then it should work fine - there is no limited functionality: resume just resumes the standard boot. The standard boot problems sounds like a problem with the drivers, which could be related to the BIOS update. If you can get a working system after resuming from recovery, try to do a full system update and look in the driver manager to see if it has some updates.